# How to get the popup window's link from Parent element?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to implement an OAUTH2 by GitLab api. For that when user click on `sign in with Gitlab` it will generate a popup window. and after successfully logged in it will redirect to a new link with a access_token on that pop-up windows.

To have that access_token i need to read the link of popup windows from parent. For that i wrote some code:

```
href='https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=some_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/manager&response_type=code&state=some_state';

function logInWithAPI(){
  console.log('hello')
  let popup= window.open(this.href, 'new_window', 'width=800,height=600, margin=0 auto');
 console.log(popup.opener.location.href);
  popup.close();
}
```

but unfortunately, i got the parent url from where user cliked on the `sign in with gitlab` on the console, rather to have the pop up windows href. Will be so glad if someone help me regarding this.

Comment: No idea what you mean by _“i got the parent href on the console, rather to have the pop up windows href”_ // The code as written makes little sense to begin with, you would just be closing the popup here almost immediately after opening it … the code doesn’t “wait” until the user has interacted with the page in the popup.

Comment: you are right. i got the base URL as it closes the pop immediately. How can i achieve the wait until user logged in? any clue please. @misorude

Comment: You can not “wait” for this at that point. You would need to do this from within the document that the user gets redirected to after authentication, inside the popup - your redirect_uri. Place code that closes the popup (and handles whatever else might need handling at that point) there.

Comment: I think you use this.href where this refer to main object it belong to so here it will refer to the location rather than refer to the variable you want to be href